# How do I check for specific types of error among those returned by ioutil.ReadFile?

Tags: go

When I use `ioutil` to read a file, it may return an error. But if I want to filter some error code, what should I do?

```
res, err := ioutil.ReadFile("xxx")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())  
}
...
```

In the code snippet above, when a file has no permission, `fmt.Println(err.Error())` will print `"open xxxxx: permission denied`.
If I want to capture this kind error, how can I know that file read failed because permission was denied?

Should I search `err.Error()` for the string `permission denied` - this looks ungraceful. Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

After trying @Intermernet solution, I found that it will not hit `case os.ErrPermission`, it will hit `default` and print `"open xxx: Permission denied"`.

@Aedolon solution is ok, `os.IsPermission(err)` can tell that a file has failed with permission deny.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the current API, `ioutil.ReadFile` doesn't guarantee any specific behaviour except that it will return `err == nil` when successful. Even the syscall package doesn't actually guarantee a specific error.

The current implementation of `ioutil.ReadFile` uses `os.Open`, which will return `*os.PathError` when failing to open a file, not `os.ErrPermission` or anything else. `os.PathError` contains a field `Err` which is also an error - in this case, a `syscall.Errno`. The string "permission denied" is produced from a private table of error messages and it's both **architecture and implementation-specific**. In my Windows machine it says "Access is denied" instead.

AFAIK, the correct method is to use `os.IsPermission(err)`, which will return `true` in case of lacking permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Per [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables), errors returned should be tested against these errors using errors.Is

```
var (
// ErrInvalid indicates an invalid argument.
// Methods on File will return this error when the receiver is nil.
ErrInvalid = errInvalid() // "invalid argument"

ErrPermission = errPermission() // "permission denied"
ErrExist      = errExist()      // "file already exists"
ErrNotExist   = errNotExist()   // "file does not exist"
ErrClosed     = errClosed()     // "file already closed"
ErrNoDeadline = errNoDeadline() // "file type does not support deadline"
)
```

As an example:

```
f, err := ioutil.ReadFile("your_file")

if err != nil {
    if errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
        // your code
    } else if errors.Is(err, os.ErrPermission) {
        // your code
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`ioutil.ReadFile()`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile) calls [`os.Open()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) and returns any error encountered there.

The [`os` package](http://golang.org/pkg/os/) defines some [file related errors](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables).

> ErrInvalid    = errors.New("invalid argument")
>   ErrPermission = errors.New("permission denied")
>   ErrExist      = errors.New("file already exists")
>   ErrNotExist   = errors.New("file does not exist")

The one you're after is `os.ErrPermission`.

```
res, err := ioutil.ReadFile("xxx")
if err != nil {
    switch err {
    case os.ErrInvalid:
        //Do stuff
    case os.ErrPermission:
        //Do stuff
    case os.ErrNotExist:
        //Do stuff
    default:
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that it will not hit **case os.ErrPermission**, it will hit **default** and print `"open xxx: Permission denied"`